# Deepspeed error: Autotuning: done with running current ds config

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am currently trying to train a model using deepspeed. The code for training is the typical pytorch training loop; I initialize the deepspeed engine via the following script:

```
    model_engine, optimizer, _, _ = deepspeed.initialize(
    model=model, 
    model_parameters=model.parameters(),
    config_params=train_params['DEEPSPEED_CONFIG'],
)
```

Then, I do regular training with a dataset, model_engine.backward(loss) and model_engine.step(). I can train for at most 4 steps it seems, before it just stops running and gives me the following:

```
[2023-05-13 00:01:23,669] [INFO] [logging.py:96:log_dist] [Rank 0] Wrote metrics to /(local_directory)/autotuning_metric.json, /(local_directory)/autotuning_metric.json
Autotuning: done with running current ds config.
```

I have no clue what the error is. I monitored the error happens - it generally happens on the 5th or 6th model_engine.step(). Suspecting a memory issue, I monitored memory usage via calling nvidia-smi in the code at several points, but there is no reason to suspect it runs out of memory - the memory before model_engine.step() is roughly the same as all of the previous times before model_engine.step().

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is something to do with your deepspeed configuration file, is there anything with `epoch` in it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. The issue was I enabled autotuning=True in my deep seed configuration file, and I *believe* that might stop the process early for whatever reason (autotuning as I understand it is to find optimal hyperparams, so maybe it stops once it has done that?)